# Usergrid Upgrade from 2.1.0 to 2.1.1

Tags: usergrid

Has anyone upgraded an existing instance of usergrid 2.1.0 to usergrid 2.1.1. I tried updating the WAR but encountered errors on start.
Error Stack Mentioned below, which suggests that it is looking for some AWS config, but I have not installed it on an aws server. Let me know if I am missing some configuration

```
enter code here

InvalidRequestException(why:unconfigured table AstyanaxLocks)
19:34:09,822 ERROR QueueListener:128 - QueueListener: threads     interrupted
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error setting up mapper
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2203)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3937)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3941)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4824)
..
..
   at   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2197)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: could not get aws access key from system properties
    at  org.apache.usergrid.persistence.queue.impl.UsergridAwsCredentialsProvider.init(UsergridAwsCredentialsProvider.java:46)
    at org.apache.usergrid.persistence.queue.impl.UsergridAwsCredentialsProvider.<init>(UsergridAwsCredentialsProvider.java:41)
    at org.apache.usergrid.persistence.queue.impl.SNSQueueManagerImpl.createSQSClient(SNSQueueManagerImpl.java:689)
    at org.apache.usergrid.persistence.queue.impl.SNSQueueManagerImpl.<init>(SNSQueueManagerImpl.java:179)
```

Comment: Found some links related to this "http://markmail.org/message/a6v66qtbtznxmvpy#query:+page:1+mid:27dyhgveuve2fmb3+state:results" and "https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/usergrid/V8A89Q9ku-M" where there is suggestion to add the entry (usergrid.use.default.queue=true) in "usergrid-deployment.properties". Let me try it and then update

Comment: no luck with any of these options. Have reverted back to 2.1.0